# MS Word - Table pasting with incorrect text wrapping property and can't change setting after pasting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code that replicates table header rows onto a bunch of other tables. I was mainly using the selection.copy and selection.paste features with the source range set to entire rows.

When I do this though, the copied rows not only don't merge, but for some reason the text wrapping settings gets changed to 'Around'. I checked both the source and destination table and their text wrapping setting is set to 'None'. I tried Selection.pasteandformat and went through all the table-specific and generic WdRecoveryType enumerations, and none of them seemed to make a difference.

I also have code in the beginning that sets the text wrapping for all tables to 'None' to ensure none of the source tables being copied have their text wrapping settings set to 'Around', but they're still being copied with the 'Around' setting.

```
For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    aTable.Rows.WrapAroundText = False
Next aTable
```

So I'm thinking fine, since I can't get it to paste with no text wrapping, then at the least I will attempt to change it manually after it's pasted. But when I attempt to change the text wrapping of the pasted rows from 'Around' to 'None', 'None' is grayed out and unable to be selected. And with the text wrapping unable to change, I can't get the two tables to combine correctly.

[image]

Just for some additional clarification the source and target table have the same number of max columns (27), but some of the rows from the source table being pasted have cells merged horizontally (i.e. one row only has one column that spans the length of the entire table). The columns in the target table are consistent in that every row has 27 columns, each with the same width.

I also did a test and tried splitting the rows in the source table with the lesser number of columns so that it has the same number of columns as the target table and it didn't seem to make a difference. The results are below where as you can see the two tables are not merged which is apparent by the table selection button on the left side after the third row. And checking the table properties the copied rows (which make up the first three columns) has text wrapping set to 'Around'.

[image]

Any thoughts or help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Pasting table rows into other tables can be difficult in MS Word. Have you tried selecting the same number of blank rows in the target table, and pasting into that selection? Select only the cells, not the entire rows (there should be not be a small block highlighted to the right of the last column). Other times, what works is pasting into the first cell of an empty row that is not selected. Of course, both tables have to have the same number of columns, with no spans.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply!  I updated my post to add information pertaining to the differences in number of columns. You are correct one of the rows has horizontal merging where there's only one cell that spans the entire width of the table. Although I tested splitting this cell so that it has the same number of columns, and then pasting it. It doesn't seem to make a difference. Still the same behavior =(

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Hey Macropod, thanks for the reply! Didn't realize non-programming questions weren't allowed on this forum, so thank you for the heads up. I'll go ahead and change my question to a VBA question as this was a problem I was originally encountering with my VBA script. I was thinking to make it more generic as having a general solution would more likely lead me to the programming solution.